# Kotlin extension function - compiler cannot infer that nullable is not null

Tags: kotlin, nullable, kotlin-extension

Let's say I have a simple class `Foo` with a nullable `String?`

```
data class Foo(
    val bar: String?
)
```

and I create a simple function `capitalize`

```
fun captitalize(foo: Foo) = when {
    foo.bar != null -> runCatching { foo.bar.capitalize() }
    else -> ""
}
```

which works fine, because the compiler infers that foo.bar cannot be null eventhough it's type is nullable. But then I decide to write the same function as an extension of `Foo`

```
fun Foo.captitalize2() = when {
    bar != null -> runCatching { bar.capitalize() }
    else -> ""
}
```

and all of a sudden the compiler is no longer able to infer that bar is not null, and IntelliJ tells me that "only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable reciever of type String?"

Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 4):

I think it's because in the first case you are calling this function:

```
public inline fun <R> runCatching(block: () -> R): Result<R> {
    return try {
        Result.success(block())
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        Result.failure(e)
    }
}
```

but in the second case you are calling function with receiver:

```
public inline fun <T, R> T.runCatching(block: T.() -> R): Result<R> {
    return try {
        Result.success(block())
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        Result.failure(e)
    }
}
```

For me, it looks like an issue in the Kotlin compiler because if you inline code of this function by yourself it will work fine:

```
fun Foo.captitalize2() = when {
    bar != null -> try {
        Result.success(bar.capitalize())
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        Result.failure<String>(e)
    }
    else -> ""
}
```

btw, if I were you I would like to write my `capitalize2` function like this :)

```
fun Foo.captitalize2() = bar?.capitalize() ?: ""
```

Comment: As suggested by @Andrei Tanana, your `runCatching` invocation in `capitalize2` is an invocation of `public inline fun <T, R>` T.runCatching(block: T.() -> R) : Result<R>` and type parameters are inferred as `runCatching<Foo, String>`: `T` is `Foo` for the compiler, not `Foo having not null property bar`, so you obtain the compilation error... When you inline the function there is no type inference between `when` and `bar.capitalize()`, so the compiler is happy and you have no errors...

Answer (score 1):

So, finally I found an alternative approach that allows us to use `runCatching` without having the problem you shows.
As in my comment to the answer of @Andrei Tanana, in your code type parameters of `fun <T, R> T.runCatching(block: () -> R) : Result<R>` are inferred as `<Foo, String>` and the compiler can't use the information that `this.bar` is not `null`.

If you rewrite the `capitalize2` function as follows

```
fun Foo.capitalize2(): Serializable = when {
    bar != null -> bar.runCatching { capitalize() }
    else -> ""
}
```

`T` is inferred as `String` (thanks of the `bar != null` case of the `when` expression) and the compiler does not complain about `this.capitalize()` invocation in the *block* passed to `runCatching`.

I hope this can help you, both as an approach than allows you to solve the problem and as explanation of the problem itself.